# Multi-legend issue in ChartLegends?

Tags: plotting, legending, charts

Been fiddling around with the legends and trying to place one in each corner and I bumped into an issue:

```
BarChart[{{12, 14, 16, 18}, {8, 10, 11, 12}, {2, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 3, 5, 7}}, 
  ChartStyle -> {Green, Blue, Red, Orange}, ChartLegends ->     
  MapThread[Placed[PointLegend[{#1},{TextCell[#2,TextAlignment->Left]},
  LegendMarkers->{#3},LegendMarkerSize->20,LabelStyle->{FontFamily->"Arial",18}
  ,Spacings->{0.2,0.2}],#4]&,{{Green, Blue, Red, Orange}, 
  {"A","B","D","C"},{{"\[FilledSquare]",22},{"\[FilledCircle]",22},{"\[FilledUpTriangle]",22}
  ,{"\[FilledDiamond]",22}},{{0.8,0.1},{0.1,0.1},
  {0.1,0.8},{0.8,0.8}}}]]
```

[image: Result]

which doesn't show all 4 legends.
But this works for PlotLegends as below

```
ListPlot[{{{0.2, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.8}}, {{0.1, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.7}}, {{0.4, 0.7}, 
  {0.7, 1.1}}, {{0.1, 0.7}, {0.8, 0.5}}}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle-> {Green, Blue, Red, Orange},
  PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledSquare], \[FilledCircle], \[FilledUpTriangle], \[FilledCircle]}
  , PlotLegends -> MapThread[Placed[PointLegend[{#1},
  {TextCell[#2,TextAlignment->Left]},LegendMarkers->{#3},LegendMarkerSize->20,
  LabelStyle->{FontFamily->"Arial",18},Spacings->{0.2,0.2}],#4]&,{{Green, 
  Blue, Red, Orange},{"A","B","D","C"},{{"\[FilledSquare]",22},{"\
  [FilledCircle]",22},{"\[FilledUpTriangle]",22},{"\[FilledDiamond]",22}},
  {{0.8,0.1},{0.1,0.1},{0.1,0.8},{0.8,0.8}}}]]
```

[image]

A workaround possibly is using `Epilog` to inset the legends into their positions. But I was wondering if anyone knew why this did not work for `ChartLegends`?

**Edit**: Added image for `ListPlot`, and fixed the syntax.

Comment: your `BarChart` example doesn't work at all (non-matching brackets etc.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out eldo, I've fixed the code up. There were unnecessary spaces and new lines in the previous.

Answer (score 4):

A work-around:  wrap the `BarChart`  with `Legended`

```
Legended[BarChart[{{12, 14, 16, 18}, {8, 10, 11, 12}, {2, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 3, 5, 7}},
   ChartStyle -> {Green, Blue, Red, Orange}, ImageSize -> 500],
 MapThread[Placed[PointLegend[{#1}, {#2}, LegendMarkers -> {#3},
   LegendMarkerSize -> 20, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 18}, 
   Spacings -> {0.2, 0.2},
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> Opacity[.5, Yellow]] &)], #4] &,
  {{Green, Blue, Red, Orange},
   {"A", "B", "D", "C"},
   {{"\[FilledSquare]", 22}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 22}, 
    {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 22}, {"\[FilledDiamond]", 22}},
   {{0.8, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.8}, {0.8, 0.8}}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a "cheat", if I interpret the desired visualization correctly.

```
bc = BarChart[{{12, 14, 16, 18}, {8, 10, 11, 12}, {2, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 3,
     5, 7}}, ChartStyle -> {Green, Blue, Red, Orange}]
p = Plot[, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    MapThread[
     Placed[PointLegend[{#1}, {TextCell[
          Style[#2, FontColor -> Purple, FontFamily -> "Arial", 18], 
          TextAlignment -> Left, Background -> Yellow]}, 
        LegendMarkers -> {#3}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
        Spacings -> {0.2, 0.2}], #4] &, {{Green, Blue, Red, 
       Orange}, {"A", "B", "D", 
       "C"}, {{"\[FilledSquare]", 22}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 
        22}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 22}, {"\[FilledDiamond]", 
        22}}, {{0.8, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.8}, {0.8, 0.8}}}]];
Show[bc, p]
```

[image]